# Django: Bypassing the database abstraction

Tags: python, sql, database, django

I have been playing arround with django for a couple of days and it seems great, but I find it a pain if I want to change the structure of my database, I then am stuck with a few rather awkward options.

Is there a way to completely bypass djangos database abstraction so if I change the structure of the database I dont have to guess what model would have generated it or use a tool (south or ...) to change things?

I essentially want this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/ (Raw SQL Queries) but instead of refering to a model, refering to an external database.

Could I just create an empty model and then only perform raw queries on it? (and set up the DB externally)

Thanks

P.S. I dont really mind if I have separate databases for the admin stuff and the app data

Comment: I don't really understand the question - or your motivation. Just because it's a bit difficult to change the db structure (although I don't know why you wouldn't use South), you want to throw out all the help given by the ORM? Plus you wouldn't be able to use the admin, or model forms - again, just because migrations are slightly tricky?

Comment: Plus, while you're in development, it's easy to just drop the db and recreate it with syncdb whenever you need to.

Comment: Using the ORM + South make it _way_ easier to change your DB structure than raw SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in your question already, just read the docs article from here: [Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)